# How to specify relationship name in code-first many to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, ef-code-first, entity-relationship

When I create two entities with many to many relationship, it will generate a relationship table in the database, is it possible to specify the table's name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes but you have to use fluent API:

```
mb.Entity<FirstEntity>()
  .HasMany(a => a.SecondEntities)
  .WithMany(b => b.FirstEntities)
  .Map(mc =>
      {
          mc.ToTable("YourTableName", "YourDbSchema");
          mc.MapLeftKey("FirstEntityKeyColumnName");
          mc.MapRightKey("SecondEntityKeyColumnName");
      });
```

Comment: +1, however it would be good to specify the version of EF for which this is true (a year later I do not know if the needs for fluent API still applies). Thanks.